# Set different volumes for different alarms

Tags: root-access, alarm

Is there any way to set a different volume for every alarm? Samsung has had such a feature for ages, but is it possible to do something similar on a stock rom? [image]

Third party apps don't seem to be able to do it.

Two workarounds possible include -
a) Using tasker to change the alarm volume before and after that particular alarm

b) Increasing/decreasing the volume of each and every alarm tone to something "louder" and something "softer", then copying these new alarm sounds to sd card/alarms

Both are significantly tedious as compared to Samsung's method.

I also have root access, if it helps.

Edit - I'm running marshmallow 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend editing the ringtone files, because you don't even need to leave your Android in order to do it.

Searching the Play Store, I've found 2 apps in question that claim to adjust volume on .ogg and mp3 files:

1. [MP3 Gain - Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keerby.mp3gain&hl=en)
2. [MP3/OGG Volume Booster - Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobooid.mp3volumebooster&hl=en)

Hope one of these do the trick for ya. I love the Tasker idea (I use Tasker in many hackish ways that would be considered unorthodox haha)

Anyway, hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the apps, I tried both, but the first wouldn't convert and the second doesn't appear to boost the volume. I still can use something like Audacity (windows), but I am looking for some other way to increase the volume - something not so tedious. What's annoying is the fact that Samsung HAS such a feature, so it can be easily implemented on Android, yet it does not seem available.

Comment: Well, what device are you trying to get it working on? If it's a Samsung device you should be able to transfer that Clock apk, but it probably won't work on other brands. Samsung probably holds the patent for individual alarm volumes.

Comment: Not Samsung, its a Motorola moto g3. I was also thinking of the apk method, but - a) not Samsung b) still pretty roundabout method. I should not need to use a different app for this. I am okay with it, but again, it won't install.

Answer (score 0):

Check my app  on Android playstore - [Alarm + Task Logger FREE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobitronix.gauravchauhan.alarmplus.free)

You can customize seperate volume, ringtone, volume fade-in(volume build up time) for each alarm.